# Problems Upgrading Mosaico 2.0 to 2.1

Tags: extension, upgrade, mosaico

Mosaico 2.1 has just been released. When I tried to upgrade from Mosaico 2.0 to 2.1 I got several errors as follows:

```
Unable to remove directory 
/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/templates

Unable to remove directory 
/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico

Failed to move /tmp/tmp-aBft2l//uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico to /sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico

Error loading module file (/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/mosaico.php). Please restore the file or disable the module.
```

Following the upgrade Mosaico then became unusable.

I upgraded Flexmailer at the same time and had no problems. I also checked folder permissions and these looked fine to me. I ran the upgrade process twice and had the same errors both times. has anyone had a similar error?

I thought it might be an error in the extension and posted an issue at [Error Upgrading from 2.0 to 2.1](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/311), but I guess it could also be my setup, though not sure why it would upgrade Flexmailer without any problems but then have errors  upgrading Mosaico.

I am on CiviCRM 5.13.5 with Drupal 7.67

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a closer look at all the folders and saw there was a symlink in the templates folder pointing to the templates folder! This must have been preventing the upgrade. I think the symlink was there because earlier we had had problems with mailings not finding the social icons and had created a symlink to solve that problem and then forgotten about it!

Once I removed the symlink Mosaico upgraded fine.